# How to do delay call a lambda function in python

Tags: python

In JavaScript, to make a delayed call to a function there's a very handy utility built in to the language called setTimeout() [yes, the naming is horrible, but hey, this is an old javascript legacy and no one has high expectations].

setTimeout() takes a function name or a lambda function and a number of milliseconds as parameters, and invokes the function in the same thread once a the event loop and the timeout reach. If timeout is zero, it will run it in the next event loop cycle.

Is there any native python object that can achieve this in a one/two liner?

Comment: I don't know that there's really anything built-in. I think the closest you could get is if you wrote your own wrapper that used either `asyncio`, or a thread/process pool.

Comment: This operation doesn't make any sense unless your code is running in an event loop. *Are* you running in an event loop? (Threading is superficially similar but has very different semantics.)

Comment: seems this is possible with sched.scheduler() but with 2 lines of code ... and no lambda ...

Comment: Python is not an event driven language. There are many event based systems out there like python's own `async` services. GUI packages like tkinter and qt implement their own. But if you aren't using an event package, there is no base event loop controller to return to.

Comment: maybe this is out of the scope of python, but as someone coming from JavaScript it looks like it's a very common/useful tool. Probably as user2357112 said - this means an event loop is requred.

Answer (score 0):

Python being the single thread application running without an event loop it seems not possible but
But in Python 3.7+ you can something similar to this  with asyncio package

try using this with event loop and async method

```
await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

which is non-blocking but  not a one-line solution

[asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)

Comment: While `asyncio.sleep` might be part of a solution, it requires a lot more context and explanation, and this isn't how you use `asyncio.sleep` anyway.

Comment: This only works if you are running in an async event loop. its not applicable to just any generic python program.

Comment: This won't answer the question, as the question is to allow code to run in later time without halting the main thread.